# DataBinding Annotation @BindingAdapter for recyclerView doesn't fire

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm getting crazy testing a 2-way databinding recyclerView.

I read lots of articles about and I'm trying to implement it through mvvm pattern.

So I have:

- Model

  ```
  public class User {

     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;


     public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
     }

      public String getFirstName() {
         return firstName;
     }

     public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
         this.firstName = firstName;
     }

     public String getLastName() {
         return lastName;
     }

     public void setLastName(String lastName) {
         this.lastName = lastName;
     } 
  }
  ```
- ViewModel

  ```
  public class UsersViewModel extends BaseObservable {

     @Bindable
     public ObservableArrayList<UserViewModel> usersTwoWay;

     public UsersViewModel() {
        usersTwoWay = new ObservableArrayList<>();
     }

     public void addUser(String firstName, String lastName) {
        usersTwoWay.add(new UserViewModel(new User(firstName, lastName)));
     }
  }
  ```

In the XML file after of course the proper init code in the head about databinding, I set the attribute for the RecyclerView

```
   app:items="@{usersViewModel.usersTwoWay}"
```

that should pass to the BindingAdpter below the data to show to the Adapter.

As last the BindingAdapter

```
   @BindingAdapter("items")
   public static void setItems(RecyclerView recyclerView, ObservableArrayList<UserViewModel> items) {

      // Some code
   }
```

Where I wrong?
Why the code of the "@BindingAdpter" isn't execute!

Comment: add notifyPropertyChanged in addUser(String firstName, String lastName)??

Comment: I tried but nothing changed!

By the way I didn't insert notifyPropertyChanged before because according le "google Guide" about "ObservableFields" you don't need it.

If I understood propertly extending BaseOservable by my usersViewModel and annotete usersTwoWay variable with @Bindable just allow me to reference it in the xml file.
Beeing then an observableObject should be enough for the binding library to automatically notify any change of che varialbe.

Comment: @CristianRosajDark could you post the solution you found so far? Thanks!

Comment: @beefBear possibly changing app:items="@{usersViewModel.usersTwoWay}" to app:items="@={usersViewModel.usersTwoWay}" might turn the wheels.